# Robotic vs roboticized

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

I'm wondering how the usage of "robotic" differs that of "roboticized". In particular, [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Roboticized) says the latter means ***transitioned from a non-robotic to a robotic state***. So, I feel if something is "robotic", a robot had been attached to it from scratch. However, if something is "roboticized", it had been initially created like a manual entity, and the robot part is latter added to it. Then, I also checked the "roboticized" entry of [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/roboticized), in which it is defined as a science fiction term. So, I am not sure whether it would be a right choice for scientific literature. Interestingly, [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=roboticized&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Croboticized%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Croboticized%3B%2Cc0) depicts zero usage of "roboticized" after 2012.

So, the two-fold question is what the difference between these two are, and whether or not "roboticized" is obsolete.

Comment: Google Books Ngram Viewer doesn't show *anything* after 2012 (if I recall correctly that was when the world ended). Try using COCA or iWeb.

Comment: First, I would compare [*robotic*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/robotic) with [***robotized***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/robotize). Note the different spelling of the latter. Although *roboticized* does exist in [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/definition/roboticized), it doesn't exist in Merriam-Webster, so it's not as widely used, at least in the US. Having said that, Ngram Viewer shows the same thing for *robotized* too, so it might not matter in terms of the actual answer to the question. (Interestingly, *mechanized* also has the same drop in usage.)

Answer (score 3):

"Robotic" is defined as:

1 : of or relating to mechanical robots
2 : having the characteristics of a robot, e.g.,
*performs with robotic consistency*

"Robotics" is derived from "robotic" and is defined as:

: technology dealing with the design, construction, and operation of robots in automation

It wouldn't be used to discuss turning someone or something into a robot. That would be "Robiticize," which is not included in M-W, but it's elsewhere defined as an alternate version of "robotize," a transitive verb defined as:

1 : to make automatic : equip with robots
2 : to turn (a human being) into a robot

I'd say that any of these terms is fine in science literature, although I'd use 'robotize' before 'roboticize.' And I'd avoid Urban Dictionary for standard definitions; it's a valuable resource but it also focuses on slang, common usage, and popular culture. It can be hard to distinguish a slang definition from a standard definition accepted in scholarly journals.

PS: An interesting side note on 'robot' is that it was coined in 1920 by a Czech author, Karel Čapek, in his play R.U.R., an early sci-fi examination of the human vs. robot theme. The word itself is derived from a Czech word meaning "serf," or "slave."

Merriam-Webster definition links:

[Robotics](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/robotics)

[Robotize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/robotize)

Your Dictionary link:

[Roboticize](https://www.yourdictionary.com/roboticization)

Wiki article on R.U.R:

[R.U.R.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.U.R.)

[MIT Tech Review - Urban Dictionary](https://www.technologyreview.com/2018/01/03/146467/the-anatomy-of-the-urban-dictionary/)

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat confusing. I don’t believe that “roboticized” is an actual word.

**Robotic** and **Robotize** are words though.
Robotic general refers to something that IS or LIKE a robot. Robotize refers to being TURNED INTO a robot or robot-like.

Comment: I feel like robotocize is a mundane synonym for automate. If you replace most of your workers with robots, you've roboticized your workplace, right? I think to robotize a workforce means to literally turn them into robots, like Dr. Who's Cybermen.

Comment: @OwenReynolds - OTOH one can automate without using robots